# Svelte is updating items that has no change in the prop

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

According to [the doc](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-afterupdate), `afterUpdate()` is triggered after updating the component. In the code below I can see by **adding/updating** an item will update all the list items.

I have passed `(list.id)` as a `#each key` which should help in updating only the item that has been modified but in this case entire list items gets updated.

In Svelte I'm not able to find what is the cause behind these updates. Like we check the difference between **oldProp** and **newProp** values in React is there a way to find cause for these updates in Svelte?

Is there anything wrong in my Svelte code? How do we update only the item that has been modified?

**Console.log**

```
(Logs after adding first item)
    list before update 1677040967648
    list updated 1677040967648

(Logs after adding second item)
    list before update 1677040969930
    list before update 1677040967648
    list updated 1677040969930
    list updated 1677040967648

(Logs after adding third item)
    list before update 1677041033328
    list before update 1677040969930
    list before update 1677040967648
    list updated 1677041033328
    list updated 1677040969930
    list updated 1677040967648
```

**List.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    export type List = {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    import { beforeUpdate, afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

    export let list: List;

    beforeUpdate(() => {
        console.log('list before update', list.id);
    });

    afterUpdate(() => {
        console.log('list updated', list.id);
    });
</script>

<div class="card">
    id: {list.id}
    <br />
    name: {list.name}
</div>

<style>
    .card {
        background-color: #ccc;
        color: #000;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
    }
</style>
```

**+page.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import ListComp from './List.svelte';
    import type { List } from './List.svelte';

    let listId: string;
    let lists: List[] = [];

    const updateList = (listId: string) => {
        const list = lists.filter((i) => i.id === listId);
        const listData = list && list.length === 1 ? list[0] : undefined;

        if (listData) {
            const filteredList = lists.filter((i) => i.id !== listId);
            lists = [...filteredList, { ...listData, name: 'test '+new Date().valueOf() + '' }];
        }
    };

    const addList = () => {
        const id = new Date().valueOf() + '';
        lists = [...lists, { id, name: 'test ' + id }];
    };
</script>

<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <div>
        Total Lists: {lists.length}
    </div>

    {#each lists as list (list.id)}
        <ListComp {list} />
    {/each}
</div>

<div>
    <button on:click={() => addList()}>Add List</button>

    <div style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <label for=""
            ><input
                type="text"
                bind:value={listId}
                style="padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #ccc;"
            /></label
        >
        <button on:click={() => updateList(listId)}>Update List</button>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    button {
        padding: 1em;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You generally should never need to use `afterUpdate`, is there a reason why you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about methods of tracking the change origin but they happen because Svelte conservatively assumes that any property of non-primitives could have changed if an object is assigned.

You can disable this per-component using

```html
<svelte:options immutable />
```

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options) / [Tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-options) (does pretty much exactly what you do)

> you never use mutable data, so the compiler can do simple referential equality checks to determine if values have changed

Of course you then cannot do something like the following and expect an update:

```js
lists[index].name = 'new name'
```